# MinGW cross-compiler and -fprofile-generate stopped working on Ubuntu after 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, mingw

I once setup profile guided optimization for cross-compiling a Windows binary on Ubuntu using `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`.  This worked fine in Ubuntu 14.04, but seems broken afterwards.  Linking after `-fprofile-generate` results in many of the `gcov_*` symbols being undefined.  This is not strange as `libgcov.a` seems practically empty.  There are quite a few posts on this topic, but I failed to find a real explanation or work-around.  Can someone clarify what is going on and -ideally- provide a work-around?

Comment: Don't you mean `-fprofile-generate`?

Comment: Yes.  Thanks for noting.  Edited.

Comment: And you did use `-fprofile-generate` for linking as well?

Comment: Yes :(  The whole project works fine on native Linux and used to work fine using MinGW for crosscompilation (and running the binary using Wine).  Something seems to have changed after either Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04 that causes the `libgcov.a` no longer to contain the (most of) the required symbols.  I wonder whether that is something changed in the way Ubuntu builds this or in the MinGW project and whether there is a work-around such as linking to a different library, building MinGW from source, etc.

Comment: I just downloaded [this package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64), and it really looks like it's missing a lot (compared to the one I have in my native version).

Comment: With _native_ you mean the normal gcc for Linux or did you build your own MinGW cross compiler?  I fear the first ...

Comment: No, I mean the mingw gcc I use on Windows.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess `-fprofile-generate` works fine there?  This would imply Ubuntu dropped support for that ...

Comment: Yes, works fine for me.